# Is a single bash script the answer? gnu plot, MySQL

Tags: mysql, bash, gnuplot

The goal is to make a graph (gnuplot) every month, containing the last 13 months of rows per month (MySQL)[so the 2-D graph will have 13 x-axis entries], one graph per customer.

Stepping back, is bash the right answer? I'd say I'm an advanced noob, but have not done for statements before, so I'm not sure how to approach this.

MySQL- I have a single mysql CLI line that I can get to run in a bash script with a variable (the time period) - it runs just fine:

```
PER003="'2013-08-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-08-31 23:59:59'"

mysql -uroot -password -h 192.168.x.x dbname -se "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename WHERE study.created_time BETWEEN $PER003;"
```

I know all the periods, as they are months of time, but in the specified format. So I could make PER004, PER005, etc. as variables.

I'm not quite worried about the gnuplot issue yet, but am wondering if am I approaching this the right way? Should I make a script per customer(each customer has their own db). Should the time periods be listed in the script or be called from an external file?(because if I have to add time periods manually each month, I'd like to do it once, rather than have to edit each customer script). Also, could I make another external file that contains each customer db and IP for the mysql command, and do a loop calling those variables for that as well?

I'm just trying to wrap my head around what all is needed and the correct approach before I dive in..... THANKS!

Comment: Maybe you want to group by month?

Comment: As this question is written now, it is in my opinion not well-suited for SO, it is too broad. You can write a script in any language, use several scripts for different tasks, do some processing in gnuplot, or directly in MySQL. If its better to have one data file or more depends on whether you need to relate one data file to another etc. And much of that depends on your workflow, your preferences, your skills and so on. Maybe you should subdivide it into several, more specific questions.

Comment: I think it'd be worth spending some time reading about a scripting language such as Python.  You can do things like external config files, generating dates, etc. in bash but it'd be a lot easier in python.